# Change value of member of class which is contained in the list

Tags: c#

I have this class `Variables`

```
public class Variables
{

    public enum DataType
    {
        INT, CHAR, BOOL, FLOAT
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DataType Type { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public Variables(string name, DataType type, object value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }

}
```

It is also assumed that `Name` is *unique*. And inside another class I have a list of variables, `List<Variables>`

```
public void Main()
{
    List<Variables> varList = new List<Variables>();
    varList.Add(new Variables("x",DataType.BOOL, true));
    varList.Add(new Variables("y",DataType.BOOL, false));
    varList.Add(new Variables("z",DataType.BOOL, true));
    varList.Add(new Variables("a",DataType.INT, 1));
    varList.Add(new Variables("b",DataType.INT, 10));

    // I need this to convert into LiNQ.
    foreach (Variables _x in varList)
    {
        if (_x.Name == "z")
        {
            _x.Value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I convert `foreach` into `LiNQ`? I tried `.Where`, `.Select` but they return `IEnumerable`. Is there a `LinQ` method that returns only a single value that matches to a given condition? eg,

```
Variables _var = varList.MethodName(LambDa Expression).....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you *can* use `Single`:

```
varList.Single(x => x.Name == "z").Value = false;
```

That will fail if there's anything other than *exactly one* match though.

Alternatives are `SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, `LastOrDefault` and `Last`. For example, if you expect "0 or 1" results:

```
var match = varList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "z");
if (match != null)
{
    match.Value = false;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response (*as usual*). I have another question, when you run this `varList.Single(x => x.Name == "z").Value = false;` does it return a value? I mean just to insure that `z` was updated or `z` was found and has been updated?

Comment: @DerekFloss thats just an assignment, it doesn't return anything

Comment: @DerekFloss: Well if you use `Single`, it will throw an exception if it fails to find a match...

Comment: @Erix: Strictly speaking, the value of the expression is the value which was assigned - so it'll always be `false` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var variablesInstance = varList.Where(v => v.Name == "z").FirstOrDefault();
if(variablesInstance != null)
{
    variablesInstance.Value = false;
}
```

You can use First instead of FirstOrDefault if you know the thing exists with that name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also First

```
varList.First(a => a.Name == "z").Value = false;
```